# How to use App detection in android wear app of React-native-android

Tags: android, react-native, wear-os

I was went to develop an `Android` app with `React-native` and then link my mobile phone app with a wear app.

So I'm going to find out if there is an interlocking app on my cell phone in the `wear` app.

I referred to the app detection function [document among Android functions.](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps#detecting-your-app)

I added values to 'app/res/values/wear.xml' and 'wear/res/values/wear.xml' according to the document description.

- app/res/values/wear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@array/android_wear_capabilities">
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>sample_app</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

- wear/res/values/wear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@array/android_wear_capabilities">
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>sample_wear</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And I checked if the phone app was installed on the paired mobile phone using Capability Client in the watch app.However, the wear app did not detect my cell phone app.

**wear/MainActivity**

```
package com.soundgym.watchos

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.view.doOnPreDraw
import androidx.core.view.isInvisible
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.core.view.setPadding
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.wear.phone.interactions.PhoneTypeHelper
import androidx.wear.remote.interactions.RemoteActivityHelper
import androidx.wear.widget.ConfirmationOverlay
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.*
import com.soundgym.watchos.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CancellationException
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.guava.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class MainWearActivity : FragmentActivity(), CapabilityClient.OnCapabilityChangedListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var capabilityClient: CapabilityClient
    private lateinit var nodeClient: NodeClient
    private lateinit var remoteActivityHelper: RemoteActivityHelper

    private var androidPhoneNodeWithApp: Node? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        capabilityClient = Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this.applicationContext)
        nodeClient = Wearable.getNodeClient(this)
        remoteActivityHelper = RemoteActivityHelper(this)

        binding.informationTextView.text = getString(R.string.message_checking)
        binding.remoteOpenButton.setOnClickListener {
            openAppInStoreOnPhone()
        }

        if (resources.configuration.isScreenRound) {
            binding.scrollingContentContainer.doOnPreDraw {
                // Calculate the padding necessary to make the scrolling content fit in a square inscribed on a round
                // screen.
                it.setPadding((it.width / 2.0 * (1.0 - 1.0 / sqrt(2.0))).roundToInt())
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this).removeListener(this, CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this).addListener(this, CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            checkIfPhoneHasApp()
        }
    }

    /*
     * Updates UI when capabilities change (install/uninstall phone app).
     */
    override fun onCapabilityChanged(capabilityInfo: CapabilityInfo) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilityChanged(): $capabilityInfo")
        // There should only ever be one phone in a node set (much less w/ the correct capability), so
        // I am just grabbing the first one (which should be the only one).
        androidPhoneNodeWithApp = capabilityInfo.nodes.firstOrNull()
        updateUi()
    }

    private suspend fun checkIfPhoneHasApp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfPhoneHasApp()")

        try {
            val capabilityInfo = capabilityClient
                .getCapability(CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP, CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE)
                .await()

            Log.d(TAG, "Capability request succeeded.${capabilityInfo.nodes.size}")

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // There should only ever be one phone in a node set (much less w/ the correct capability), so
                // I am just grabbing the first one (which should be the only one).
                androidPhoneNodeWithApp = capabilityInfo.nodes.firstOrNull()
                updateUi()
            }
        } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
            // Request was cancelled normally
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Capability request failed to return any results. \n reason : ${throwable.message}")
        }
    }

    private fun updateUi() {
        val androidPhoneNodeWithApp = androidPhoneNodeWithApp

        if (androidPhoneNodeWithApp != null) {
            // TODO: Add your code to communicate with the phone app via
            //       Wear APIs (MessageClient, DataClient, etc.)
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed")
            binding.informationTextView.text =
                getString(R.string.message_installed, androidPhoneNodeWithApp.displayName)
            binding.remoteOpenButton.isInvisible = true
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Missing")
            binding.informationTextView.text = getString(R.string.message_missing)
            binding.remoteOpenButton.isVisible = true
        }
    }

    private fun openAppInStoreOnPhone() {
        Log.d(TAG, "openAppInStoreOnPhone()")

        val intent = when (PhoneTypeHelper.getPhoneDeviceType(applicationContext)) {
            PhoneTypeHelper.DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "\tDEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID")
                // Create Remote Intent to open Play Store listing of app on remote device.
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(ANDROID_MARKET_APP_URI))
            }
            PhoneTypeHelper.DEVICE_TYPE_IOS -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "\tDEVICE_TYPE_IOS")

                // Create Remote Intent to open App Store listing of app on iPhone.
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(APP_STORE_APP_URI))
            }
            else -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "\tDEVICE_TYPE_ERROR_UNKNOWN")
                return
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(intent).await()

                ConfirmationOverlay().showOn(this@MainWearActivity)
            } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
                // Request was cancelled normally
                throw cancellationException
            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                ConfirmationOverlay()
                    .setType(ConfirmationOverlay.FAILURE_ANIMATION)
                    .showOn(this@MainWearActivity)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainWearActivity"

        // Name of capability listed in Phone app's wear.xml.
        // IMPORTANT NOTE: This should be named differently than your Wear app's capability.
        private const val CAPABILITY_PHONE_APP = "sample_app"

        // Links to install mobile app for both Android (Play Store) and iOS.
        // TODO: Replace with your links/packages.
        private const val ANDROID_MARKET_APP_URI = "market://details?id=com.sample.app"

        // TODO: Replace with your links/packages.
        private const val APP_STORE_APP_URI = "https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/com/id11111115"
    }
}
```

Why can't I detect it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that the package name of the mobile phone app and the package name of the watch app were different. This name must be the same to read the information.

[Reference document](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging#Studio)

> NOTE : In the case of `React-native` projects, the same changes should
> be made to the `wear app` because there is a default `sign key for debug`.

> wear/build.gradle

```
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../app/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'signingConfigs storePassword of app/build.gradle'
            keyAlias 'signingConfigs keyAlias of app/build.gradle'
            keyPassword 'signingConfigs keyPassword of app/build.gradle'
        }
    }
```